# How do I compile Sass files in Rollup and inject them inline? (In Shadow Root)

Tags: sass, rollupjs

I have a simple scss file that looks like this...

```
@use "@material/top-app-bar/variables" as top-bar;
.jrg-viewport{
  with: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  height: calc( 100% - #{top-bar.$row-height} );
}
```

If I run `sass src/components/viewport/index.style.scss dist/output.css --load-path=node_modules` then the output looks like...

```
.jrg-viewport {
  with: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  height: calc( 100% - 64px );
}
```

Which is how I would expect it, however, if I try to run using rollup...

```
import postcss from 'rollup-plugin-postcss'
const pcss = postcss({
    extensions: ['.scss'],
    plugins: [
        autoprefixer
    ],
    use: [
        [
            'sass', {
                includePaths: [path.resolve('node_modules')]
            }
        ]
    ]
});
...
plugins: [
    resolve(),
    pcss,
    pug(),
    terser()
],
```

But when I try to run I get....

> [!] (plugin postcss) Error: Expected digit.
>
> src/components/viewport/index.style.scss 5:36  root stylesheet

Why is one failing and one working fine? Basically at the end of the day I need the output of sass to be a string I can embed in a innerHtml.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm wondering the same thing.